# How to count children of the tree in Kotlin Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to know the number of questions in my database, but it still whows me zero. Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

```
private fun countQuestions() {
    val countQuestionRef = instance
        .getReference("/course/$courseUid/parts/$coursePartUid/tests/")

    countQuestionRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) { }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (p0.exists()) {
                p0.children.forEach {
                    countQuestions++
                }
                scoreBar.text = countQuestions.toString()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you are observing the count of children.  Are you logging a value somewhere?  Could you also show the values of the variables used to build the path, so we can see that they match what you show in the picture?

Comment: Please edit the question and add what Doug asked for and respond with @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not **tests**, you should write **test**.

```
getReference("/course/$courseUid/parts/$coursePartUid/test/")
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, it was such a stupid mistake. Thank you!